# macOS status bar: Change keyboard layout icon

Tags: macos, catalina, icon, menu-bar, language

Can I change from this:

[image: atrocious, ugly low-res language bar icon]

low resolution language icon to this:

[image: simple, nice looking white text]

simpler icon?

I do like the lock-screen version more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to get rid of the flag, you can use the identical ABC input source instead.

If you make a copy of the US layout with [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/), you can add any icon you want.  If you do not provide any icon, just the .keylayout file, then you should get exactly the "simpler icon" you show in your question (except the US will come after the icon).

Comment: hm, can I get rid of flags altogether? I also have this 
https://i.imgur.com/PBn97UE.png

Comment: @mekkanizer If you make a custom layout with no icon, you get a generic keyboard icon in place of a flag.

Comment: How do I create a custom layout with no icon, please? It didn't work out with Settings app, so I downloaded Ukulele, but it looks like an alien interface to me :?

Comment: Adding keyboard icon doesn't seem an option unfortunately as that icon won't be properly inverted with light/dark theme switch

Comment: Go the Help menu in Ukelele to get lots of info about how to use it.  Very simple in my opinion.  Re light/dark switch see  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ukelele-users/cnM_e5jjYdk